# Jumping to lines in Java

Tags: java, c++, goto

I have just now started learning Java and one of the differences I noticed from C++ and VB is that Java has no goto statements, which I tend to use a lot while programming.

Is there any way I could jump between lines using another statement? I tried to use break and continue but to no avail (I might be doing something wrong).

Here is the code with goto statements and how I want it to operate:

```
public class HelloWorld {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    jump1:
    System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");
    String method = sc.nextLine();
    if (method.equals("tax")) tax();
    else {
        System.out.print("Please input a valid method. \n\n");
        goto jump1;
    }  
}
```

What is a good replacement for the goto commands?

Comment: `Go To`s for almost every occasion have been discouraged for decades already. Ever heard of `loops`?

Comment: You should read [Go-to statement considered harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF), wisdom from 1968.

Comment: `goto` isn't completely useless (it is more readable sometimes), but using it a lot is almost definitely a bad thing.

Comment: you can do gotos in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: The best replacement for `goto` is modern programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid "goto" statements in all languages, according to the rules of "structured programming", instead using if-then-else or do or while or for loops to control program flow.

Java DOES have a sort of "goto" statement that you COULD use to only slightly modify your code, but consider the `while` loop below and the `break` statement, which jumps out of the loop.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String method = "";
    while(! method.equals("tax")){
      System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");
      method = sc.nextLine();
      if(method.equals("tax"))
        break;
      System.out.print("Please input a valid method. \n\n");
    }
    tax();
  }
```

The `break` statement enables your "Please ... valid" statement to display. You could also use this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String method = "";
    while(! method.equals("tax")){
      System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");
      method = sc.nextLine();
    }
    tax();
  }
```

I also kind of like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String method = "";
    while(1==1){
      System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");
      method = sc.nextLine();
      if(method.equals("tax")
        break;
      System.out.print("Please input a valid method. \n\n");
    }
    tax();
  }
```

You might go to the Java tutorials; they're good.

Answer (score 6):

A `while` loop in this instance.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

For this (very specific) instance you could put

```
System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");

String method = sc.nextLine();
while (!method.equals("tax"))
{
    System.out.print("Please input a valid method. \n\n");
    method = sc.nextLine();
}
tax();
```

Obviously this only works if your only expected correct input is "tax", but it's a structure to build on.

Comment: I may be prejudiced but this code shows clearly what is intended, where for the OP's code my eyes scan it up and down at least three times. But can't one write a `do..while` loop in Java?

Comment: @Jongware you can indeed write do-while loops in java, and such a loop would probably be ideal for this

Comment: Course you can, I was just quickly answering :-) I also think that the OP first needs to learn about the basic loops without any nuances.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to put your `if-statement` in a `while-loop` by using the `hasNextLine()` function, which will loop until theres no more lines left to iterate over:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    // Your code..
}
```

For more info regarding the function check [Scanner::hasNextLine documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ScannerhasNextLine.htm).

Comment: Please avoid 'this' links where you could easily write a (shortened) URL.

Comment: @Jongware shortened URLs are strongly discouraged, see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup) where people are putting considerable time into removing these links. What the poster had originally done is far prefable to a mystery shortened URL

Comment: @RichardTingle, for a second i was doubting myself, but i will reverse my post as i found that much more suitable than a shortened link which may have a risk of vanishing/break.

Comment: @RichardTingle: apologies, led astray by wording. I dislike that type of 'shortened' URLs as much as the next person. I meant something like 'check [Scanner::hasNextLine documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ScannerhasNextLine.htm)'.

Comment: @Jongware, now we speak the same language, i agree on that perspective and will make a correction.

Comment: @Jongware ah, now that I can get behind

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use a do-while-loop, which will do the statement first and will only repeat if the statement is true:

```
public class HelloWorld {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  boolean right = true;

    do {
      if(right)
        System.out.print("What do you want to calculate? ");
      else
        System.out.print("Please input a valid method. \n\n");

      String method = sc.nextLine();
      boolean right = false;
    } while (!method.equals("tax"));
    tax();

    }  
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket.